# JQuery plugin is not working with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, api, angular

as i am new to angular2 i am expecting to find out a solution for the following scenario.
The jQuery plugin is not working after getting the data -http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

i got issues on   *var owl = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#breif');
            owl.owlCarousel();

My full code are given bellow

**angular 2 component:**

```
/ beautify ignore:start /
import {Component, OnInit , ElementRef, Inject    } from '@angular/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {CAROUSEL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/carousel';
/ beautify ignore:end /
import {Api} from '../../../../services/api';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'breif',
    directives: [CAROUSEL_DIRECTIVES],
    template: require('./template.html')
})
export class BreifComponent implements OnInit    {

  elementRef: ElementRef;
  breifs: Object;

public myInterval:number = 5000;
public noWrapSlides:boolean = false;
public slides:Array<any> = [];

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef ,  private api: Api) {
          this.elementRef = elementRef
          this.loadBreif();

      }

      ngOnInit() {

        **var owl = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#breif');
        owl.owlCarousel();**

      }



    loadBreif(){
      this.api.getBreif().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.breifs = data.result.articles;

        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => {

        }

      )

      }

}
```

template.html

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="breif" >
<div class="item" *ngFor="let breif of breifs"><h4>{{breif.title}}</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I posted a workaround of using owl owl.carousel@2.1.4 with angular 2.0.0 + webpack + jQuery@3.1.0.

Some of the issues I faced was with the jQuery plugin.

Please be more specific about the exception/error...

First U'll need to install the above^ packages via npm or similar.
Then -->  npm install imports-loader 
(for using owl within component otherwise u'll get fn is undefined...since third-party modules are relying on global variables like $ or this being the window object...).

*In case you are using WebPack:*

imports-loader as follow:

```
{test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'}
```

Also u can use jQuery with webpack:

```
var ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
```

In the plugin section of webpack.common.js:

```
plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
```

For images loader:

```
{
   test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/,
   loader: 'file?name=public/img/[name].[hash].[ext]'
}
```

*public/img -- images folder

CSS loader:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
   loader: 'raw'
}
```

The vendors.js file should import the following:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'owl.carousel';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css';
```

Please be aware that owl.carousel 2 is still use **andSelf**() deprecated function of jQuery so we need to replace them with the new version of **addBack**().

Goto node_modules folder in the owl package  dist/owl.carousel.js:
replace all the occurrences of **andSelf**() with --> **addBack**().

*Now is the angular 2 part:*

**owl-carousel.ts:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'carousel',
    templateUrl: 'carousel.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['carousel.css']
})
export class Carousel {
    images: Array<string> = new Array(10);
    baseUrl: string = './../../../../public/img/650x350/';
}
```

**`carousel.component.ts:`**

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'owl-carousel',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class OwlCarousel implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit{
    @Input() options: Object;

    $owlElement: any;

    defaultOptions: Object = {};

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        for (var key in this.options) {
            this.defaultOptions[key] = this.options[key];
        }
        var temp :any;
        temp = $(this.el.nativeElement);

        this.$owlElement = temp.owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.$owlElement.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
        this.$owlElement = null;
    }
}
```

**carousel.component.html:**

```
<owl-carousel class="owl-carousel"[options]="{navigation: true, pagination: true, rewindNav : true, items:2, autoplayHoverPause: true, URLhashListener:true}">
    <div class="owl-stage" *ngFor="let img of images; let i=index">
        <div class="owl-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="{{baseUrl}}{{i+1}}.png"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

Make sure to bootstrap everything in the app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import  {OwlCarousel} from './components/carousel/carousel.component';
import  {Carousel} from './components/carousel/owl-carousel';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OwlCarousel,
        Carousel
    ],
    providers: [appRoutingProviders],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```